# Segmentation Fault(core dumped) Queue Operation using linked list

Tags: c, queue, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I have written a code in c to implement queue operations using linked list, like insertion, deletion, peek and display.

I use vscode to run and compile my codes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}node;
typedef struct Queue{
    node *front;
    node *rear;
}queue;
queue *q=NULL;
int isempty(queue *);
void create(queue *);
queue *insert(queue *);
queue *delete(queue *);
void display(queue *);
void peek(queue *);
int main(){
    int o;
    create(q);
    do{
        printf("\nQueue Operations");
        printf("\n1. Insert");
        printf("\n2. Delete");
        printf("\n3. Peek");
        printf("\n4. Display");
        printf("\n5. Exit");
        printf("\nEnter Option : ");
        scanf("%d",&o);
        switch(o){
            case 1:
                insert(q);
                break;
            case 2:
                delete(q);
                break;
            case 3:
                peek(q);
                break;
            case 4:
                display(q);
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid Option");
                break;
        }
    }
    while(o!=5);
}
void create(queue *q)
{
    q->front=NULL;
    q->rear=NULL;
}
queue *insert(queue *q){
    node *p;
    p=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("Enter Data : ");
    scanf("%d",&p->data);
    if(q->front=NULL){
        q->front=p;
        q->rear=p;
        q->front->next=q->rear->next=NULL;
    }
    else{
        q->rear->next=p;
        q->rear=p;
        q->rear->next=NULL;
    }
    return q;
}
int isempty(queue *q){
    if(q->front==NULL)
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
queue *delete(queue *q){
    node *p;
    int t;
    p=q->front;
    t=isempty(q);
    if(t==1)
        printf("Queue Empty");
    else{
        q->front=q->front->next;
        printf("Value Deleted : %d",p->data);
        free(p);
    }
    return q;
}
void peek(queue *q){
    int t;
    t=isempty(q);
    if(t==1)
        printf("Queue Empty");
    else
        printf("Peek:%d",q->front->data);
}
void display(queue *q){
    node *p;
    p=q->front;
    if(p==NULL)
        printf("Queue is Empty");
    else{
        while(p!=q->rear){
            printf("%d\t",p->data);
            p=p->next;
        }
        printf("%d\t",p->data);
    }
}
```

I am not understanding why i am getting a segmentation fault in this question.

This code was in my book i Just blindly copied this one but still i am getting the error.
I tested the code in online compilers as well to be sure that my machine is not having any fault but still getting the same issue.

If anyone can help me out.

Comment: If you have a large piece of code already written and not tested, and it turns out to crash, then you should start by using a *debugger* to catch the crash and locate when and where in your code it happens. Once you know that, you should try to minimize the code to the most minimal example replicating the crash, in essence creating a [mre]. Once you have this minimal code it's easier to debug and see what happens and how to solve it. Then add the other parts of the code, piece by piece, testing in between (which you should have done from the beginning).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i tried doing it. When i debugged the code i am getting error in the create(),  where i am initializing `q->next=NULL`.

Comment: When you call `create(q)` in the `main` function, where does `q` point? Remember that a pointer is really what it sounds like, it points to somewhere else, and for it to be valid your code must actually make it point somewhere valid.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is a bad idea when functions depend on a file scope variable as in your program where functions depend on the variable `q`.

```
queue *q=NULL;
```

Secondly, you are using a null pointer in the function create.

```
void create(queue *q)
{
    q->front=NULL;
    q->rear=NULL;
}
```

that invokes undefined behavior.

There is no great sense to declare a pointer of the type `queue` instead of declaring an object of the type `queue`.

So instead of this definition in the file scope

```
queue *q=NULL;
```

it is much better to write in main

```
queue q = { .front = NULL, .rear = NULL };
```

or

```
queue q;
create( &q );
```

The function `isempty` can be written simpler

```
int isempty( const queue *q )
{
    return q->front == NULL;
}
```

The function `insert` should not ask any question. The value that is added to the queue should be passed to the function as an argument.

It is the caller of the function that should provide the value.

Pay attention to that allocation of memory can fail, You should process such a situation in the function. Otherwise again the function can invoke undefined behavior.

Also instead of using comparison you are using assignment in this if statement

```
if(q->front=NULL){
```

The function can be written the following way

```
int insert( queue *q, int data )
{
    node *p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) );
    int success = p != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        p->data = data;

        if ( q->front == NULL )
        {
            q->front = p;
        }
        else
        {
            q->rear->next = p;
        }

        q->rear = p; 
    }

    return success;
}
```

In the function `delete` you are not updating `q->rear` if the queue contains only one node.

Again the function should not issue any message. It is the caller of the function that decides whether to output a message.

The function should be defined the following way

```
int delete( queue *q )
{
    int success = !isempty( q );

    if ( success )
    {
        node *p = q->front;
        q->front = q->front->next;

        if ( q->front == NULL ) q->rear = NULL;

        free( p );
    }

    return success;
}
```

The function `peek` should return by reference its data member `data` because the user of the function can want to process the value.

The function can look the following way

```
int peek( queue *q, int *data )
{
    int success = !isempty( q );

    if ( success )
    {
        *data = q->front->data;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The parameter of the function `display` should have the qualifier `const` because the queue is not changed within the function.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void display( const queue *q )
{
    if ( isempty( q ) )
    {
        puts( "Queue is Empty" );
    }
    else
    {
        for ( const node *p = q->front; p != NULL; p = p->next )
        { 
            printf( "%d", p->data );
            if ( p != q->rear ) putchar( '\t' );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

typedef struct Queue
{
    node *front;
    node *rear;
} queue;

int isempty( const queue *q )
{
    return q->front == NULL;
}

void create(queue *q)
{
    q->front=NULL;
    q->rear=NULL;
}

int insert( queue *q, int data )
{
    node *p = malloc( sizeof( *p ) );
    int success = p != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        p->data = data;
        
        if ( q->front == NULL )
        {
            q->front = p;
        }
        else
        {
            q->rear->next = p;
        }

        q->rear = p; 
    }

    return success;
}

int delete( queue *q )
{
    int success = !isempty( q );

    if ( success )
    {
        node *p = q->front;
        q->front = q->front->next;

        if ( q->front == NULL ) q->rear = NULL;

        free( p );
    }

    return success;
} 

int peek( queue *q, int *data )
{
    int success = !isempty( q );

    if ( success )
    {
        *data = q->front->data;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( const queue *q )
{
    if ( isempty( q ) )
    {
        puts( "Queue is Empty" );
    }
    else
    {
        for ( const node *p = q->front; p != NULL; p = p->next )
        { 
            printf( "%d", p->data );
            if ( p != q->rear ) putchar( '\t' );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    queue q;
    create( &q );
 
    int option = 5;
    
    do
    {
        printf("\nQueue Operations");
        printf("\n1. Insert");
        printf("\n2. Delete");
        printf("\n3. Peek");
        printf("\n4. Display");
        printf("\n5. Exit");
        
        printf("\nEnter Option : ");
        
        scanf( "%d", &option );
        
        switch( option )
        {
        case 1:
        {
            printf( "Enter Data : " );
            int data;
            
            if ( scanf( "%d", &data ) == 1 )
            {
                if ( !insert( &q, data ) )
                {
                    puts( "Error: not enough memory." );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                puts( "Invalid input." );
            }
            
            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            if ( !delete( &q ) )
            {
                puts( " Error: queue is empty." );              
            }
            else
            {
                puts( "First element of the queue has been deleted." );
            }
            
            break;
        }
        
        case 3:
        {
            int data;
            if ( peek( &q, &data ) )
            {
                printf( "The value is %d\n", data );
            }
            else
            {
                puts( "Error: the queue is empty." );
            }
            
            break;
        }
        
        case 4:
        {
            display( &q );
            break;
        }           
        
        case 5:
        {
            break;
        }
        
        default:
        {
            puts( "Invalid Option" );
            break;
        }
        }       
    } while( option != 5 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Queue Operations
1. Insert
2. Delete
3. Peek
4. Display
5. Exit
Enter Option : 1
Enter Data : 1

Queue Operations
1. Insert
2. Delete
3. Peek
4. Display
5. Exit
Enter Option : 1
Enter Data : 2

Queue Operations
1. Insert
2. Delete
3. Peek
4. Display
5. Exit
Enter Option : q
Enter Data : 3

Queue Operations
1. Insert
2. Delete
3. Peek
4. Display
5. Exit
Enter Option : 4
1   2   3

Queue Operations
1. Insert
2. Delete
3. Peek
4. Display
5. Exit
Enter Option : 5
```

Pay attention to that you need also to write a function that will clear the queue that is that will free all the allocated memory in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

q is not pointing to anything.  When you deference it in create() you are writing to random memory which will usually cause a crash.

You should define q as type queue (no pointer) and pass the address of it to the sub functions.

Comment: Not random memory. Because `q` is originally a global variable it will be initialized as a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever pointer is dereferenced, it should be allocated fair amount of memory through malloc before its usage. Hence, while creation of linked list, queue pointer should be allocated and passed back to main for using it. Attached modified queue creation code below for reference,

```
queue* create(queue *q)
{
q= (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
q->front=NULL;
q->rear=NULL;
return q;
}
```

Update calling function in main as well.

Comment: It is now allocating the queue but then in the insert() when i call the `q->front==NULL` it is showing segmentation fault there. Do i have to allocate the q in every section to run?

Comment: in the code you wrote q->front=NULL not q->front==NULL make sure you wrote it correctly as I pointed in my answer ...I find you writing it here correct but in the question written wrong ....make sure it is == not =

Answer (score 0):

The create function needs allocating memory **you can't create without allocating memory** whenever you allocate it inside create function or pass queue with already allocated memory (you can't do both solutions at same time just one of them) and the first one is preferred for making organized code.

```
queue* create(queue *q)
{
q= (queue*)malloc(sizeof(queue));
q->front=NULL;
q->rear=NULL;
return q;
}
```

Another bug in **insert function**     `if(q->front=NULL){` that will make q->front actually assigned to null and it will lead to segmentation fault  , you should  need checking `==` not assigning `=`

`if(q->front==NULL){` will make it works more correctly